# Python GUI, библиотека pywebview, активная сессия

Tags: python, gui, сессия

Когда я запуская GUI приложение, открывается сайт компании, я логинюсь(я в системы), перехожу на другие сайты через меню.
Вопрос в том, как сделать так, ЧТОБЫ Я ОСТАВАЛСЯ ЗАЛОГИНИНЫМ НА ПЕРВОМ САТЙЕ, ссесия должна быть активная, но при этом я мог спокойно переходить на другие сайты через меню. Сессия должна быть активной пока приложение запущено.
Создавать второе окно не вариант.
Какие есть идеи, код прилагаю.
dex_call() активная сессия.
Ссылку на сайты я беру из текстового документа

```
import webview
import webview.menu as wm
# Открываем текстовый файл
dex = open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/dex(не удалять).txt','r')
# Читаем по строкам
dexi = dex.readlines()
# Закрывает текстовый документ после чтения
dex.close

# сайт компании
def dex_call():
    # Open website
    webview.create_window(
    'Тёплый контакт', ('тут сайт компанииl'),
    # Маштабирование
    zoomable=True,
    # Подтверждение закрытия
    confirm_close=True,
    width=1280,
    height=720
    )

# Menu
# Меню релаьных звонков
def menu_dex_call():
    active_window = webview.active_window()
    if active_window:
    active_window.load_url(dexi[2])

# Меню учебные проекты
def menu_educational_projects():
    active_window = webview.active_window()
    if active_window:
    active_window.load_url(dexi[4])

    # Меню срочные проекты
        def menu_urgent_projects():
        active_window = webview.active_window()
        if active_window:
        active_window.load_url(dexi[6])   
                        
# Меню zoom конференция
def menu_zoom():
    active_window = webview.active_window()
    if active_window:
    active_window.load_url(dexi[8])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dex_call()
    menu_items = [
        wm.Menu(
        'Меню',
        [
            wm.MenuAction(dexi[1], menu_dex_call),
            wm.MenuSeparator(),
            wm.MenuAction('Учебные проекты', menu_educational_projects),
            wm.MenuSeparator(),
            wm.MenuAction('Срочные проекты', menu_urgent_projects),
            wm.MenuSeparator(),
            wm.MenuAction('Zoom ', menu_zoom),
            wm.MenuSeparator()
        ]
    )
]
webview.start(menu=menu_items, private_mode=False)

введите сюда код
```